# Maven exhibits strange behaviour from cmd windows 7

Tags: windows, maven, cmd

I am using maven in a project here at work and I've come up to a rather strange (at least for me) problem. When I do an: mvn package everything seems ok but the output of mvn disappears as soon as maven completes. To test it more I just did a: mvn --help and I could not see the output. As soon as the command finishes the prompt is cleared. I am doing my work now using redirections: mvn package > out and then: type out in order to see the output. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanx!

Solved: To whoever finds this useful. At the end of mvn.bat there was the line

```
    cmd /C exit /B %ERROR_CODE%
```

which I had to comment out like this:

```
    @REM cmd /C exit /B %ERROR_CODE%
```

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of Maven? I have win7 64-bit and have had no issues with Maven 2. It might be worth checking your mvn.bat to ensure no-one's been messing with it and put a clear screen command at the end or something.

Comment: You can post your Solution as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the MAVEN_TERMINATE_CMD is set to on. If it is unset it:

```
set MAVEN_TERMINATE_CMD=
```

Check that the mvn.bat script in maven's bin directory doesn't contain an exit command without the /b option. It should end with the following line:

```
cmd /C exit /B %ERROR_CODE%
```

If neither alternative solves your problem, set the MAVEN_BATCH_PAUSE variable to on:

```
set MAVEN_BATCH_PAUSE=on
```

before you run maven. This should cause mvn.bat to wait for a keystroke before exiting.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that I'm still puzzled about what the original cause of your problem is. You shouldn't need to do anything special just to be able to see Maven's output!

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of how to use mvn in a batch file under Windows 7 and Maven 3.2.1

```
:: ensure variables do not propagate outside this batch call
setlocal

:: save current directory and change to ".."
pushd ..

:: tell mvn.bat to exit after done, not to spawn cmd (why is this by default..)
set MAVEN_TERMINATE_CMD=on
:: spawn new cmd prompt to handle the mvn call, which blocks and exits
cmd /c mvn clean install

:: do something fancy here

:: cd to saved directory (pushd)
popd
:: pause the script and require pressing a key to continue
pause
```